# What effect is using /etc/cron.deny supposed to have?

Tags: centos-7, crontab

Does adding a user to cron.deny deny cron jobs from running or the ability to edit the crontab file?

The man pages say:

> **Running cron jobs** can be allowed or disallowed for different users.  For this purpose, use the cron.allow and cron.deny files.

I ask because after adding a user to cron.deny, the user was denied from running crontab -e however the commands on the existing cron jobs of this same user were still allowed to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/cron) *cron* does not check cron.allow and cron.deny. If the jobs were already present in the crontab database, then *cron* will run them.

/etc/cron.deny and /etc/cron.allow only decide who can use the crontab command. From the man page:

> For classical crontab there exists cron.allow and cron.deny files. If cron.allow file exists, then you must be listed therein in order to be allowed to use this command. If the cron.allow file does not exist but the cron.deny file does exist, then you must not be listed in the cron.deny file in order to use this command.